# How to deploy Python Flask application in Azure App Services if the requirements.txt has multiple private Git repos as dependencies

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I'm trying to deploy a Python Flask application in Azure App Services using GitHub actions. I can see plenty of examples of how to do it online, but they all seems to have the requirements.txt containing publicly available packages.
In my case the requirements.txt contains references to private GitHub repos and those repos contain references to some more private GitHub repos in their requirements.txt

References in the requirements.txt use the following format:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/<org>/<repo>#egg=library
```

The application builds fine in GitHub environments and in local machines.
But when I try to deploy to Azure App Services through GitHub actions I get the following error.

[image: Error]

The GitHub actions workflow file looks like this:
[image]

Do I need to setup ssh keys in Azure App services or do I need to configure App services in a different way for installing private GitHub python dependencies?

Thanks,
Sak

Comment: Search online for azure documentation on private github ssh access for deployment you may have came across [this help item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we are using GitHub actions instead of Azure DevOps... The GitHub actions workflow file uses the ssh private key to build and it succeeds, does deploy step maybe needs the ssh credentials passed over somehow?!?

Comment: Sorry, from the wording of the question and the screenshot it was not exactly clear how or where this is failing (you noted it built fine on GitHub environments" but failure "to deploy to Azure App Service" it conjures the idea that failure happens on Azure). When your code runs inside a VM it won't have any credentials whatsoever, so you need to pass whatever credentials to checkout the file securely - this includes when using `pip` on GitHub actions - see [issue](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/202) for related problem, you may need to manually checkout all private repos like so.

Comment: Alternatively, just use the [GitHub Actions Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets) features to securely apply the relevant secrets to the build environment (on GitHub Actions) to allow the proper checkout of private repositories.

Comment: We use secrets, In the GitHub actions workflow you can see secret "SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" being used to access the private repos. And it works in GitHub during build stage (Also as part of tox CI pipeline in GitHub). Wondering if Azure App Service is going to do pip install while deploying how it can have the ssh credentials.

Comment: You might have a better chance of quicker response if you open an issue at the appropriate github action repository.